# How to to get conditional rendering inside an iterator which is inside a scroller?

Tags: lightning, css, uiscrollerwrapper

`If ui:scrollerWrapper is uncommented, the class in card element does not work.

```
<!--            <ui:scrollerWrapper  class="scroll" >-->
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.commentsData}" var="comment" indexVar="key">
        <lightning:card class="{!comment.Color == 'grey' ? 'grey' : 'blue'}" aura:id="{!comment.Color}+{!key}">
            {!comment.text}
        </lightning:card>
    </aura:iteration>
    <!--    </ui:scrollerWrapper>-->
```

Comment: can you post full code and show what exactly is not working

Answer (score 0):

```
<aura:component controller="CommunityCaseDisplayController" implements="force:hasRecordId, forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes, flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="commentsData" type="Object[]" />    
<!--            <ui:scrollerWrapper  class="scroll" >-->
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.commentsData}" var="comment" indexVar="key">
        <lightning:card class="{!comment.Color == 'grey' ? 'grey' : 'blue'}" aura:id="{!comment.Color}+{!key}">
            {!comment.text}
        </lightning:card>
    </aura:iteration>
    <!--    </ui:scrollerWrapper>-->
</aura:component>
```

Comment: lightning:card CSS Class does not take if used inside scrollerWrapper:
<aura:iteration items="{!v.commentsData}" var="comment" indexVar="key">
        <lightning:card class="{!comment.Color == 'grey' ? 'grey' : 'blue'}" aura:id="{!comment.Color}+{!key}">
            {!comment.text}
        </lightning:card>
    </aura:iteration>